# Strange behavior of the UIBarButtonItem with Accessibility Button Shape

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiaccessibility

Application shows `UIBarButtonItem` in the `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem` successfully.

Button created like this.

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:Localized(kSelect) style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                                        target:self action:@selector(onSelectButtonPressed:)];
```

And everything works fine only when i enable Enable Button Shapes in Accessibility `leftBarButtonItem` is disappearing but is still active and i can select this button. After debagging it is possible to highlight that button text is changed to the white.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `UIButton` and then customise it according to your need, then instantiate `UIBarButtonItem` from it.

```
UIButton *myBtn = [[UIButton alloc] init];
//
// do your necessary customisation on myBtn
//

UIBarButtonItem *barBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:myBtn];
```